# Pine Script - How to get the high of current day, till current bar

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I would like to get the high value of the current day. And the high value should be taken from previous bars of the current day.

I tried this code

```
security(syminfo.ticker, "D", high, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

But the problem is that it is taking the high value of the current day after all the current day's candles.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newDay = change(time("D")) != 0

float todaysHigh = na

if newDay
    todaysHigh := high
else if high > todaysHigh[1]
    todaysHigh := high
else
    todaysHigh := todaysHigh[1]
```

`if` block can also be written as a ternary :

```
todaysHigh := newDay ? high : high > todaysHigh[1] ? high : todaysHigh[1]
```